# Unable to call instance method from SensorEventListener native JNI method

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am implementing SensorEventListener in native method as follows (to make calculations faster):

```
public class GPSLogger extends Service
    implements SensorEventListener {

     public native void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event);
     public void startLocationUpdates() { // some code }
}
```

The corresponding JNI implementation gets called. But I am trying to call startLocationUpdates() from the native C code as follows:

```
jclass objcls = (*env).GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID methid = (*env).GetMethodID(objcls, "startLocationUpdates", "()V");
if (methid == NULL)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "[IFL]", "startLocationUpdates not found");
else
    (*env).CallVoidMethod(obj, methid);
```

In this case methid is NULL. and there is an exception in ADB log saying

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lmy/package/GPSLogger;.startLocationUpdates()V"
```

What could be wrong?  I even tried geting objcls as

```
jclass objcls = (*env).FindClass("my/package/GPSLogger");
```

but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after adding proguard rule (to prevent obfuscation of method name):

```
-keep class my.package.GPSLogger { void startLocationUpdates(); }
```